# Combine MySQL IN operator and LIKE

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, count, duplicates

How can I combine an `IN` operation and `LIKE` operation in MYSQL?

In my case, I want to find duplicate records containing a particular substring. For example, I have P123 and 123. I am removing P to find the duplicate record 123. Then I want to find all records that **contains** `123`.

I have the following MySQL query but I cannot figure out how to make add the wildcard search.

```
    SELECT *
    FROM table
    WHERE field IN
    (
        SELECT * FROM
        (
            SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(`field`,'T',''),'P','') as x
            FROM table
            GROUP BY x
            HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
        ) AS subquery
    )
```

Comment: There's no need for the `SELECT * FROM` intermediate subquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't really need a wildcard. Just apply the same transformation on the joined column as you did in the suqbuery:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE REPLACE(REPLACE(`field`,'T',''),'P','') IN (
    SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(`field`,'T',''),'P','') as x
    FROM table
    GROUP BY x
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
)
```

Note that if you are running MySQL 8.0, you can also do this with window functions, which gives a shorter query and *could* be more efficient:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT 
        t.*, 
        COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY REPLACE(REPLACE(`field`,'T',''),'P','')) cnt
    FROM table
) t
WHERE cnt > 1
```

Comment: Sometimes you just need to look at the question from a different angle!

Answer (score 0):

You can join with a subquery instead of using `IN`.

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.*
FROM table as t1
JOIN (
    SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(`field`,'T',''),'P','') as x
    FROM table
    GROUP BY x
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
) AS t2 ON t1.field LIKE CONCAT('%', t2.x, '%')
```

Note that searching for a substring means it won't match the exact number. If you're looking for records that contain `123`, you'll match `P1234`, `P1123`, etc. If you only want to match the exact same number, GMB's answer will be better (you can also do that with a `JOIN`).